# Multiple forms (hyperref TextField) on one line using tabular

Tags: tables, hyperref

I am wanting to put 2 TextField blocks on the same line.  The formatting seems correct but the boxes do not render. If I do not use `tabular` the boxes render but they are on different lines.

```
\begin{tabular}{ l l l l }
    Start Date: & \TextField{} & End Date: & \TextField{}\\
\end{tabular}
```

As you can see, the form boxes do not display:
[image]

I am guessing this might be due to some width issue and the form boxes not "fitting" into the table cell.

Is there anything else I should be doing here to make those boxes render properly?

Comment: Make a complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\TextField{Start Date:}\quad \TextField{End Date:}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l l }
     \TextField{Start Date:} &  \TextField{End Date:}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

should result in the following output:

[image]

Comment: your first example worked. We have a *massive* custom document class that I am guessing is mucking with tabular. Thanks!

Comment: @TrevorSteen. My bet would be that you have an outdated hyperref. But as you didn't provide a minimal example one can't compare the log-files.